# Don't know what goes wrong when I try to bake a normal map

Tags: texture-baking, normals, normal-map

Hey guys im trying to make a mew low poly mesh and get the detail from the high poly one onto the low poly one.[image]

However whenever I try to bake the normal map it comes out weird like that on the corner.
[image]

Also heres the material on the high poly mesh if it helps[image]

Is there a problem with the meshes, or how I go about baking? If there's something else im doing wrong please tell me.

Comment: have you given a Subdivision Surface modifier to your low-poly? It may be the problem...

Comment: No I haven’t I made it on top of the other one from scratch

Comment: I may be wrong but it looks like it's because of your low-poly topology... are you planning to give it a Subdivision Surface modifier? In that case do it before the baking. If you don't I guess you'll have this result. But maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Okay I’ll try baking a couple more times today and if I can’t get it right I’ll share the file, thanks btw